# Ban SiteNames Multisite

Tags: multisite, site-url

Is there a way to ban site names from being able to be created. For example we have subfolders like domain.com/site
Is there a way to ban bad words from being registered. So domain.com/bad would be blocked?

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

You can filter `domain_exists`, a check that runs before a site is registered. If you return a positive integer, WordPress will not create that site. Despite its name, that filter lets you check the path too.

Sample code, not tested:

```
add_filter( 'domain_exists', function( $result, $domain, $path ) {

    // Already taken, no need for further checks.
    if ( $result ) {
        return $result;
    }

    $blacklist = [
        'domains' => [
            'assets.example.com',
            'wordpress.example.com',
        ],
        'paths' => [
            'wp-admin',
            'wp-includes',
            'wp-content',
        ],
    ];

    if ( in_array( $domain, $blacklist['domains'] ) ) {
        return 1;
    }

    $path = trim( $path, '/' );

    if ( empty ( $path) ) {
        return $result;
    }

    if ( in_array( $path, $blacklist['paths'] ) ) {
        return 1;
    }

    return $result;
}, 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Adding a comment to this for reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/domain_exists

Comment: It might be a better answer if `$blacklist` was explained with some comments.

Comment: Also, I had no idea you could create an array with a simple wrap with brackets `[ array_key => array_value, array_key1 => array_value1 ]`. That is slick!

Comment: @NathanPowell Why would you explain `$blacklist`? That's pretty clear, right? :)

Comment: To me it is, yes. So is `$result`. The meat and potatoes is the $blacklist var. Commenting one without the other seemed like a sidetrack to the OP question.

Comment: @NathanPowell Comments should explain the **why** only, and even that only in cases that aren't clear. Here they would be noise and do more harm than good. That's probably a matter of style.

Comment: Regardless of style, your code is solid. Thanks for being here dude, always helpful!